# Unsure how to initialize a new object that is a copy of another object's object parameters in JAVA

Tags: java

Essentially, I am making a small program that deals with double values and enums as inputs and returns some output. The problem is that I need to make a new object as such:

For this problem I am unable to import classes or use static methods, so I have been trying to clone the two objects without any imported classes. I'm unsure if my "Example z = new Example(t)" line is false or what. I can set the values of 't' to another set private 'Example' object, but I don't know how to send that information to the object 'z'.

```
public class Example{
    private double temp;
    private Scale scale;
    private char start;
    public Example(double temp){...}
    public Example(double temp, Scale scale){...}
    public Example(Example input){
              /*I don't know what to put in here in order
              in order to copy the input to a new object*/
    }
}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Example t = new Example(-10000.1, Scale.FAHRENHEIT);
    Example z = new Example(t);
}
```

Comment: Research for `Object#clone()` and copy-constructors

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the following techniques based on your use case:

- Use `clone()` if the class implements Cloneable.
- Create a clone manually. If there is a `constructor` that accepts all
  parameters, it might be simple, e.g `new Example( ex.temp, ex.scale,
  ... )`.
- Use `serialization`. If your object is a graph, it might be easier to
  serialize/deserialize it to get a clone.

you can refer to [this](https://www.journaldev.com/17129/java-deep-copy-object) for code samples

Answer (score 2):

```
public Example(Example input){
    this.temp = input.temp;
    this.scale = input.scale;
    this.start = input.start;
}
```

might help ;)

Comment: You'd have to extract the primitives from the `Scale` object as well

Comment: Don't think so. Guess a this = input might work too. The new objects address reference based on this.

Comment: By assigning `this = input` you're essentially changing the reference of your object (applies to any other reference type for that matter) to that of `input` and not cloning the object; such that any subsequent changes you make to`input` will reflect on the new object

Comment: Ok, you are right!

Comment: As the OP didn't say he wants a deep copy, this looks good!